# How to indicate to users what went wrong

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a wonderful query:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[r1:IS_LOCATED_IN]->(l1:Location) where c.name=$char
MATCH (l1:Location)-[r2:IS_CONNECTED_TO]->(l2:Location) where
    l2.name=$newlocation and c.turns >= r2.cost and l1 <> l2
SET c.turns = c.turns - r2.cost
DELETE r1
CREATE (c)-[:IS_LOCATED_IN]->(l2)
return c,l2
```

It moves the character from one location to another, using up turns. It is self-contained and atomic. The issue is that any of the following could happen:

- the $char var could not refer to an actual character
- the $newlocation var could not refer to an actual location
- the new location could not be connected to the old location
- the cost could be greater than the tuns the character has
- the old and new locations could be the same location

If any of these happen,I just get no results back - Which makes it impossible to inform the user of what went wrong.

I am a bit of a cypher neophyte. Is there a way with multiple WITH clauses or something to keep the nice atomic nature of the query and still be able to return something indicating what went wrong?

UPDATE: Well I got it all working, but it is a long way to go to be atomic. I probably won't do it like this because there may be other processing and logic going on here anyway, but it was a good learning experience:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Character {name: $character})-[r1:IS_LOCATED_IN]->(l1:Location)
WITH c,r1,l1
OPTIONAL MATCH (nl:Location) where nl.name=$newlocation
WITH nl,r1,c,l1
OPTIONAL MATCH (ll:Location)-[r2:IS_CONNECTED_TO]->(l2:Location) 
    WHERE ll.name = l1.name and l2.name = $newlocation
WITH l2,r2,nl,r1,c
OPTIONAL MATCH (c2:Character) 
    WHERE c2.name = $character and  c2.turns >= r2.cost
WITH c2,l2,r2,nl,r1,c
FOREACH (a IN CASE WHEN l2 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL THEN [c2] ELSE [] end |
    SET a.turns = a.turns - r2.cost
    DELETE r1
    CREATE (a)-[:IS_LOCATED_IN]->(l2)
)
RETURN c2,l2,CASE 
    WHEN c is null THEN 'bad character'
    WHEN nl is null THEN 'bad location'
    WHEN l2 is null THEN 'not connected'
    WHEN c2 is null THEN 'too few turns'
    ELSE 'success' END AS message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use `OPTIONAL MATCH`, `WITH` and a `CASE` statement at the end to evaluate possible scenarios.

For instance... instead of

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[r1:IS_LOCATED_IN]->(l1:Location) where c.name=$char
```

you could have an

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Character)-[r1:IS_LOCATED_IN]->(l1:Location) where c.name=$char
WITH c
...
RETURN CASE
    WHEN c IS NULL THEN "Character not found"
    ELSE "something else
END AS message
```

Comment: you will have a little more work to do for optionally performing the `SET` and `DELETE` when the character or the location, etc is not matched.